# How to stop "Couldn't sign in" notifications?

Tags: notifications, email

I have my Nexus 9 (on 5.x) connected to my iCloud account for email. It works fine, I even get notifications for new email. It can connect to the server just fine.

However, I get notifications from Gmail around every 15-20 minutes saying "Couldn't sign in" with my iCloud email address.

I don't like my tablet and wrist vibrating that often with useless notifications. How can I turn these off (or, ideally, fix the problem) without turning off notifications for real email?

Comment: What app do you use to fetch emails from iCloud?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to disconnect and connect again the iCloud account with Gmail app? If the problem is still there, you could try to use a different app: with your setup you should have (maybe disabled) a so called 'Email' app.